# Dynamic Images in Tableau

Tags: image, tableau

A Tableau Workbook I'm working on has different users logging in to see the data for their company. In the dashboard I have created a dynamic image that shows the customer logo depending on who is logged in. I created this by going to the Map drop down and using Background Images. The field that controls which image is seen, is a customer dimension which lists all of the customers in the database.

The issue I'm having is that some users, internal users, can see all of the customers. When these users log in I need the logo to either disappear or show the main company's logo. The customer column doesn't these users listed because they aren't customers. This means I don't have a column to use as a filter.

I followed every step in this website and hopefully it will provide enough of an example since I can't share the original workbook. Here is the website I used to build this: https://www.thedataschool.co.uk/nora-ann-weststrate/tableau-creating-filter-dependent-images/

Comment: Perhaps add an 'internal customer' to the list of users?

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix by creating this calculated field:

{EXCLUDE [ColumnName] : COUNTD([ColumnName]) = 23}

This would exclude all of the customers when all were shown. Then I added this to the Filters card and the color marks card.